# Can I make a Docker image with the current computer's settings as it is?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I have built Apache2 web server in Offline environment on Debian environment. Can I make this setting as a Docker Image? If yes, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have docker installed on your Debian host. Basic skeleton will be like this. 
You would create a Dockerfile with the following content.

```
# Filename: Dockerfile 
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

and then run

```
$ docker build -t my-apache2 .
```

You can also expose port 80 or 8080 in the Dockerfile and have it start httpd server by default.

Comment: Is it possible with scratch (blank image) without using httpd image?

Comment: _FROM scratch_ is a key word that you can use to create **base images**. From your question, it appears to me like you want to package the entire Debian OS kernel and everything inside of your host VM. You can look at this [script](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/dockerize-disk.sh) which converts a disk image in to a docker container.